# Parsing a table in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to use Selenium / Python to read a basic HTML table. Each row is formatted like this:

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><font face="Arial"><font size=2><b><a href="https://www.lyngsat.com/tvchannels/id/TV-Polri.html">TV Polri</a></b></td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><a href="https://www.lyngsat.com/freetv/Indonesia.html"><img src="/f.gif" title="LyngSat Free TV" height=15 width=15 align=absbottom border=1></a><br></td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><font face="Verdana"><font size=1>MPEG-4</td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><font face="Verdana" size=1><font color="darkgreen">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;16</font></td><td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><font face="Verdana" size=1>&nbsp;&nbsp;66</td>
<td bgcolor="#ffffbb"><font face="Verdana" size=1>&nbsp;142&nbsp;In<br></td>
<td bgcolor="#d0ffff"><font face="Verdana" size=1>new</font></td>
</tr>
```

The table does not include IDs or classes to latch off, so I'm selecting rows (related to TV channels) using the contents of href:

```
text = "https:www.lyngsat.com/tvchannels/"

for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"%s")]' % text):
    print(elem.text) # Prints TV Polri, the name of the TV channel
```

I'd now like to iterate through the sibling elements to pull the other information in the row (e.g. "MPEG-4", "16","66", "142 In", "New"). It would be simplest if I could just move to the next sibling with something like:

```
channel_elem = elem.nextsibling()
```

... but this function does not seem to exist. I've also tried finding the other siblings directly using 'following-sibling':

```
for channel_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td//a[contains(@href,"%s")]/../../following-sibling::td' % text):
    # Read 2nd sibling (Channel)
```

but this doesn't find any elements, and also feels like a roundabout solution.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if Selenium has that capability. I'd try using BeautifulSoup since, IIRC, you can find siblings with it

Comment: [Siblings in BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)

Comment: I'm not sure how xpath handles that 'font' element in your html, but have you checked that '//td//a[contains(@href,"%s")]/../../following-sibling::td' path?  It looks like there's an extra backstep.  try ''//td//a[contains(@href,"%s")]/../following-sibling::td' instead

Comment: Thank you. Beautiful soup is the better solution.

Answer (score -2):

how about selecting the row, then finding the columns from that?

```
for row_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"%s")]/../..' % text):
    for col in row_elem.find_elements_by_xpath('./td'):
        print(col.text)
```

Comment: That won't work because you can't use `.text` on an element collection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake @JeffC.  I've edited to include the inner loop of the column elements